# Rails 4.2: How to generate schema.rb with inserts as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I want to migrate parts of my app to Rails, so I want to generate the `schema.rb` for my database.

To do that, I simply configurate the Rails app to point to the database in question, however I have a bunch of inserts that has to be done as well, which is in the database as entries in their respective tables.

The rake command `rake db:schema:dump` does not generate the inserts needed.

Is there any way I can generate the inserts (which represent the current data entries in the database)?

I'm using Rails 4.2.2 with MySQL.

Thanks,

Johan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the folder `db` there should be a `seeds.rb`. This is the file you use to 'seed' your database with data with the essentials:

```
country_list = [
  [ "Germany", 81831000 ],
  [ "France", 65447374 ],
  [ "Belgium", 10839905 ],
  [ "Netherlands", 16680000 ]
]

country_list.each do |name, population|
  Country.create( name: name, population: population )
end
```

You can run `rake db:seed` to run this.

If you need to migrate your data to the seed file then try adding this to `lib/tasks/export.rake`:

```
namespace :export do
  desc "Prints Country.all in a seeds.rb way."
  task :seeds_format => :environment do
    Country.order(:id).all.each do |country|
      puts "Country.create(#{country.serializable_hash.delete_if {|key, value| ['created_at','updated_at','id'].include?(key)}.to_s.gsub(/[{}]/,'')})"
    end
  end
end
```

Obviously you will need to change this for each table you'd like to keep, but run this with `rake export:seeds_format`

Comment: Is there any way I can generate the seeds file? I tried the `seed_dump` gem but I didn't get it to work properly, more precisely it doesn't do anything -.-. Thanks

Comment: @JohanS I mean, that's a separate question, but see edit

Answer (score 1):

The schema file is the canonical source of your database's structure, not its content (hence it doesn't record `INSERT`s and the like).

To keep a record of your database's content a Rails project, you may want to dump them to `seeds.rb`, that way you can load them using `rake db:seed`.

The [`seed_dump`](http://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump) library is useful for this:

> Seed Dump is a Rails 4 plugin that adds a rake task named `db:seed:dump`.
>
> It allows you to create seed data files from the existing data in your database.

Comment: Hi, This sounds nice, however when I run this, nothing happens. Do you know which database it is pointing at? I did a `rake db:schema:dump` before and stuffed that into a migration.

Comment: `rake db:seed:dump` requires the Seed Dump library to be installed. The rake command won't work without it. To see your database configuration, you'll want to check your project's `database.yml`.

Comment: I have installed the gem, however it doesn't do anything. The `database.yml` file is configured, however I haven't added any models extending `ActiveRecord::Base`, do I need to do that?

Comment: Yes, since it's your ActiveRecord models which will be persisted to the database.